# How to get a list of all SVN commits in a repository and who did what to what files?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

I'm needing to get a list with all the revisions and files modified in each one, and by who.

Is that possible?

I need to know who user did the most changes to the repo and what changes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In the root of the working copy, type

```
svn log -v
```

This will give you everything. If this is too much then use `--limit`:

```
svn log -v --limit 100
```

See the [log command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) (on windows), then you can use the "Show log" function to see a list of all commits.

In this dialog you can also open some statistics/graphs such as "number of commits per week" (for each user).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at svn log and svn blame.

Answer (score 2):

Try the demo of [FishEye by Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/FishEyeDownloadCenter.jspa).  This tool can give you all the stats about your repo that you would ever want.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a tool called '[svnplot](http://code.google.com/p/svnplot)' (which I admit was inspired by the output of StatSVN). Its written in python and available on Google code. http://code.google.com/p/svnplot.  You can see the sample output at http://thinkingcraftsman.in/projects/svnplot/index.htm

Basically it converts the Subversion log history into a 'sqlite' database and then queries sqlite database to generate graphs. You can write your own queries using the created sqlite database.

See if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn log --verbose
```

Should do the trick. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re15.html

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [StatSVN](http://wiki.statsvn.org/)

> StatSVN retrieves information from a
>   Subversion repository and generates
>   various tables and charts describing
>   the project development, e.g. timeline
>   for the lines of code, contribution of
>   each developer etc. The current
>   version of StatSVN generates a static
>   suite of HTML or XDOC documents
>   containing tables and chart images.
>
> StatSVN is open source software,
>   released under the terms of the LGPL